# RX JAVA + Retrofit sdk generation using Swagger codegen

Tags: android, swagger, retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

I want to generate sdk using swagger codegen which can give me generated sdk with Observable as callback like below :

> @POST("oauth/token")
>   Observable < TokenResponse>
>   getRepository(@Query("grant_type") String grantType);

Comment: take a look from here https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sampleapp/api/RestService.java

Comment: And the question is ...

Comment: @Saveen Thank you,but I guess you did not get my question.I want to create a sdk using Swagger codegen which creates an interface like above for every api calls made..I want to know about the command actually which for java is : 
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.4.jar generate -i http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs -l java -o retrofit/ -c config.json

Comment: @Selvin And the question is what I asked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can generate a Java Retrofit API client with RxJava enabled using the following command as an example:

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate \
-l java -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json \
-c /var/tmp/retrofit2rx/java-petstore-retrofit2rx.json \
-o /var/tmp/retrofit2rx
```

and the JSON config file (/var/tmp/retrofit2rx/java-petstore-retrofit2rx.json) defines the following:

```
{
  "library": "retrofit2",
  "artifactId": "swagger-petstore-retrofit2-rx",
  "useRxJava": true,
  "hideGenerationTimestamp": true
}
```

You can then find the auto-generated code under the `/var/tmp/retrofit2rx` folder.

Please use the latest stable version of Swagger Codegen instead: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases, or pull the latest master of swagger-codegen to enjoy the enhancements and bug fixes.

To get a list of options for customizing the Java API client, please run the following command:

`java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar config-help -l java`

UPDATE: On May 2018, about 50 top contributors and template creators of Swagger Codegen decided to fork Swagger Codegen to maintain a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.I tried it just now and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Swagger Gradle Codegen](https://github.com/Yelp/swagger-gradle-codegen), 
Generates Kotlin code and Retrofit interfaces, with RxJava2 for async calls, Moshi for serialization and ThreeTenABP for Data management

Comment: Does not support OpenApi 3

Comment: Yes it’s not support OpenApi 3 yet.

Answer (score -1):

For codegen you can use this for the JSON config file, is very similar that above response but I had to use useRxJava2 instead of useRxJava, like this: :

```
 {
    "library": "retrofit2",
    "artifactId": "swagger-petstore-retrofit2-rx",
    "useRxJava2": true,
    "hideGenerationTimestamp": true,
 }
```